# When taking a flight from Belfast to London do you need a photo ID?

Tags: uk

When taking a flight from Belfast to London do you need to present a photo ID (driving license/passport) and do you go through passport control?

Does this change if you are not a British or Irish national?

Comment: Definitely no passport control, this is an internal UK flight... but passport depends who you're flying with, some airlines require it like RyanAir.

Comment: who are you flying with?

Comment: If you do not have a photo ID, how do you demonstrate whether or not you are a British or Irish national?

Comment: @BritishSam This is a general question. I am not making the journey. If there is no passport control, does this mean Irish and British citizens have a separate lane, or is border control delegated to the Irish EU border?

Comment: @Ben Belfast is in the United Kingdom, as is London. No borders are being crossed.

Comment: If not "border", what is the correct term for the legal boundary between Northern Ireland and England? Either way my question is about observable facts: do you need photo ID and do you go through passport control when making this journey?

Comment: @Ben You do not go through passport control on a domestic flight in the UK. Photo ID requirements are up to the airline.

Comment: @Ben there is no legal boundary, it would be like flying from London to Manchester. Like Richard says, photo ID is down to what the airline requires. Flying to Dublin (Rep of Ireland) would be a bit different.

Comment: Northern Ireland has different laws to England. So there is a legal boundary?